# Como pegar o Text de um ListView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Como posso pegar o `Text` do meu `Label` que esta dentro de um `ListView` sem usar o `FindControl` (`Item.FindControl("lblCodigoEdit") as Label).Text`), ou seja acessar diretamente 
o valor que tem no meu `lblCodigoEdit` ?

```
foreach (var Item in livCamposForm.Items)
{
    var dataKey = livCamposForm.DataKeys[Item.DataItemIndex];
    if (dataKey == null)
        continue;

    var IdCampoFormulario = (Int32)dataKey.Value;

    var qrCampsForm = DBCtx.tb_CamposFormulario.Find(IdCampoFormulario);

    Int32 Conta = Convert.ToInt32((Item.FindControl("lblCodigoEdit") as Label).Text);
}
```

No ListView

```
<ItemTemplate>
<tr class="<%#setClass(Container.DataItem)%>">
  <td>
    <asp:Label ID="lblCodigoEdit" class="<%#setClass(Container.DataItem)%>" runat="server"
      Text='<%# Eval("Codigo")%>' />
  </td>
  <td>
```

O motivo para isso é ter um desempenho melhor uma vez que com o `FindControl` todo o controle é carregado quando na realidade eu só precisava do `Text` do controle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu coloquei um exemplo de como eu faria isso sem usar o `FindControl` que é o que você quer.

Bem na verdade a recuperação dos dados e pelo próprio `Datakey` do `ListView` e não mais da `label`.

Quero deixar claro que eu não sei se essa é a forma correta e se você terá o ganho de desempenho que você precisa, é necessário fazer um teste com muitos registros para saber.

**Aspx**

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" DataKeyNames="CodigoPar, CodigoImpar" ID="livCamposForm">
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblCodigoPar" runat="server"
                Text='<%# Eval("CodigoPar")%>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="CodigoImpar" runat="server"
                Text='<%# Eval("CodigoImpar")%>' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

```
<br />
<asp:Button ID="btnFazerAlgumaCoisa" Text="text" runat="server" OnClick="btnFazerAlgumaCoisa_Click" />
<br />
<asp:Label ID="lblPar" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<br />
<asp:Label ID="lblImpar" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<br />
```

**C#**

```
public class Teste
{
    public int CodigoImpar { get; set; }
    public int CodigoPar { get; set; }
}

public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{        
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Teste> LstTeste = new List<Teste>
        {
            new Teste(){ CodigoPar = 0, CodigoImpar = 1},
            new Teste(){ CodigoPar = 2, CodigoImpar = 3},
            new Teste(){ CodigoPar = 4, CodigoImpar = 5},
            new Teste(){ CodigoPar = 6, CodigoImpar = 7},
            new Teste(){ CodigoPar = 8, CodigoImpar = 9},                
        };

        livCamposForm.DataSource = LstTeste;
        livCamposForm.DataBind();
    }

    protected void btnFazerAlgumaCoisa_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < livCamposForm.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            var codigoPar = livCamposForm.DataKeys[i].Values["CodigoPar"];
            lblPar.Text += codigoPar; 

            var codigoImpar = livCamposForm.DataKeys[i].Values["CodigoImpar"];
            lblImpar.Text += codigoImpar; 
        }  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que conheço não há forma de fazer isso diretamente, exceto se você utilizar javascript na sua lógica. O id do seu controle quando é renderizado não é o mesmo que você utiliza ao desenvolver, porque o `label` é repetido n vezes de acordo com a quantidade de itens do `listview`. Você não consegue acessá-lo diretamente. Para encontrar o controle `label`, você precisa dizer para o servidor a linha e qual elemento encontrar.

Como já disse, você pode tentar utilizar Javascript para encontrar o elemento, utilizando a classe como seletor ou algum atributo "data-...". Realizar sua lógica via JS e colocar em algum campo escondido (`HiddenField`) para utilizar depois no servidor.